# Win32: How to create a bordless popup window

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, win32gui

Win32 API provides many styles for window creating and I'm looking for a style that can remove  a one-pixel border from the window that I created with this code:

```
DWORD dwExtStyle = 0;
DWORD dwStyle = WS_POPUPWINDOW;

    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    dwExtStyle,
    className,
    windowName,
    dwStyle,
    300,
    300,
    100,
    100,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

and I got the result:

[image]

What combination of flags can remove the black border from the window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `WS_POPUP` instead of `WS_POPUPWINDOW`.

The macro `WS_POPUPWINDOW` is actually a set of flags:

```
#define WS_POPUPWINDOW (WS_BORDER | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU)
```

The `WS_BORDER` flag is the one responsible of your black square.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to create a window with WS_POPUP only but there was no any window on the desktop. Than I found that I created a window with NULL background brush. It's strange that the NULL-brush ignored when I'm creating a window with WS_POPUPWINDOW (there appeared a white color) and I'm creating a window with WS_POPUP the background brush is used normally.

Comment: @MaxFX The background brush and the WS_POPUPWINDOW should not be related, AFAIK. But note that if your window does not redraw itself (WM_PAINT) and does not have a background brush nor a border, it will behave just like a chameleon, keeping whatever image happened to be in the screen before it and will be easy to miss.